# How to change the color of bootstrap navbar dropdown when clicked?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change the bootstrap navbar dropdown link's color when clicked or selected.  Right now it changes to the specified color for a split second, and then just switches back to the default gray.  Here is my CSS:

```
li.dropdown:active {
           background-color: teal;
 }
```

The drop down:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="nav-text">Office Info</span> <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="faq.php">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="privacy.php">Privacy</a></li>
    <li><a href="health.php">Health Links</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `!important` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```css
.navbar .navbar-nav > li.open > a:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav > li.open > a:focus {
  background-color: teal;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>

        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.dropdown ~ li a:hover{
    background-color: teal;
```

}

the `~` is a tilde the css general sibling select